# Access bloginfo, get_option, and plugins_url from a non-core php file

Tags: plugin-development, wp-load.php, bloginfo, options, plugins-url

I am creating a plugin that has a php file in the plugin directory which is accessed directly via a custom rewrite url.

I need this file to be able to use the three functions mentioned in the title.

At the moment, I am including the wp-load.php file which gives me access to all of these functions. However, I've been reading that wp-load shouldn't be included because it may not always be in the same place and it includes wordpress files that may not be needed.

This is how I'm including wp-load:

```
$wp_base = explode($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
require($wp_base[0] . '/wp-load.php');
```

I've found that the functions I need are located in these wordpress files:

```
wp-includes/general-template.php
wp-includes/functions.php
wp-includes/link-template.php
```

Should I instead include only these three files, and will they always be located in the same place?

Or is there a better way to go about do this?

Thanks

Comment: There is most certainly a better way to do this. If you include these files, you are setting yourself up for all sorts of maintenance issues. What are you trying to do by executing a PHP file directly? My guess is that there is a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are already accessible if you use the [rewrite API](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api). When your file is parsed WordPress has loaded already, so **do not include core files a second time**.

Comment: The functions don't seem to exist without including wp-load, but I'm using the same method to create my rewrite as explained in the link you provided. After the rewrite is created I found this line added to my .htaccess file: `RewriteRule ^mypage$ /wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/mypage.php [QSA,L]` Wouldn't this bypass wordpress and load the php file directly?

Comment: Then something strange happend. Usually, there is no need for an extra line in the .htaccess.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm not rewriting to index.php so it adds the rule to htaccess instead of running it through wordpress. But I'm not sure how I could use index.php and still have it load my page.

Comment: Did you read the page I linked to? Everything is nicely explained there. For a code example see my [Speed Dial Plugin](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Opera-Speed-Dial-Preview).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I didn't read the article well enough, but I got it to work by adding the query variable then requiring my php page on the template_redirect hook.